# Parse unnamed mappings in JSON using Jackson

Tags: json, parsing, jackson

I have some JSON in the following format that I'm trying to parse with Jackson -

```
"response":{
"response_inner":{
"a":{"field1":2,"field2":0,"field3":5,"field4":0,"field5":[{"field5_1":"b","field5_2":1},{"field5_1":"c","field5_2":1}]},
"d":{"field1":2,"field2":6,"field3":11,"field4":0,"field5":[{"field5_1":"c","field5_2":1},{"field5_1":"b","field5_2":1}]},
"response_inner_bool":false
}
}
```

Here "a", "b" etc. are some Strings that can change in each response.

I've created a Java object to represent the 'response_inner' (let's call it ResponseInner) and another to represent the object containing the field?s (let's call this one FieldInfo) but I'm not sure how to parse this using the @JsonCreator and @JsonProperty annotations - ResponseInner objects can contain any number of String -> FieldInfo mappings.

I tried parsing it like this -

```
public class Response {
    private ResponseInner responseInner;

    @JsonCreator
    public Response(@JsonProperty("response_inner") ResponseInner responseInner) {
        this.reponseInner = responseInner;
    }
}

public class ResponseInner {
    private Map<String, FieldInfo> stringToFieldInfoMap;
    private boolean responseInnerBool;

    @JsonCreator
    public ResponseInner(Map<String, FieldInfo> stringToFieldInfoMap, @JsonProperty("response_inner_bool") boolean responseInnerBool ) {
        this.stringToFieldInfoMap = stringToFieldInfoMap;
        this.responseInnerBool = responseInnerBool;
    }
}
```

But it complains that Argument #0 of constructor has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-paramater constructor annotated as Creator. Any suggestions for how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using the `stringToFieldInfoMap` within ResponseInner anyway.  Why do you need to pass it as parameter?

If you do need it in that class, you can simply set it via a setter rather than passing it to constructor.

Alternatively, you could perhaps utilize a third class which deals with that actual mapping of the response, which consumes the Response object (which would in turn consume the ResponseInner object which has had the Map removed from it).  This would actually allow you to decouple the mapping logic from the response logic perhaps.

```
public class MappedResponse {
    private Map<String, FieldInfo> stringToFieldInfoMap;
    private Response response;

    public MappedResponse(Map<String, FieldInfo> stringToFieldInfoMap, Response response) {
        this.stringToFieldInfoMap = stringToFieldInfoMap;
        this.response = response;     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but not sure I understand how this relates to parsing the JSON sample I included using Jackson? Also I do need stringToFieldInfoMap in ResponseInner, this was just an excerpt from my code.

Comment: @user654703 The issue seems to be that you currently have a parameter that you are passing into @JsonCreator annotated constructor, which will only work with a single parameter method signature.  I was suggesting either passing the `stringToFieldInfoMap` to the `InnerResponse` class after instantiation, or perhaps refactoring the class structure.

Comment: I've tried changing the code to manually parse the stringToFieldInfoMap so that I can detect the case when the String is 'correctlySpelled' and the fieldInfo is actually a boolean but then I'm not sure how to parse the FieldInfo from a JSON object (the 'field5' is not recognized). But it sounds like what you're suggesting is slightly different - could you include a code example to illustrate?